# Frame manufacturer?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'd like to know the manufacturer of this aluminium MTB frame. It's serial number starts with the letters "AF". Any ideas?

[image: lat]
[image: back]
[image: ped]
[image: lat2]

Comment: Without any identifying markings like a [head tube badge](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/35/ff/ff35ff27298d2e727b21134d5fd64b14.jpg) it's very difficult to identify a frame as many are made overseas. Even bikes from different brands with use identical frames with a different paint job. It looks like a pretty basic hybrid frame.  Is there any reason you want to identify it?

Comment: As far as I know it was taken from a MTB... I'm just curious, as I bought it made from different used and new parts. Unfortunately there is no badge :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know.  However the short head tube, the modern looking cranks and pedals, modern brakes suggest its in the last 10 years.

Not sure if the fork is the same age as the frame, because most MTBs had front suspension.   Perhaps the front fork was from something older.

The wheels may be original, because they appear well matched and to both have a double rim thickness. Front axle has nuts and a quick release on the rear, so one of those has likely changed.

Of course the leather saddle and handgrips, and the moustache handlebar are more recent additions too, probably done as part of the fixed wheel / single speed conversion.   Paint looks relatively new too.  Consider adding 
discrete reflectors like  http://www.dx.com/p/bike-wheel-spoke-abs-safety-reflective-tube-reflector-grey-12-pcs-228130#.VWgjBer4uCg

Chain tension might cause you problems over time - MTBs have fairly close to vertical dropouts, where as single speeds like BMX frames have a lot more adjustment forward and backward.

If its good quality and works for you, care for it and should last decades.  Finally, be aware that nice looking bikes get stolen more, and black bikes get stolen more.  So nice looking black bikes get stolen a lot more.

Comment: Almost everything come from a different part, I think fork and frame came together (I have another 15 years old original spanish Otero MTB without suspension), but wheels, cranks... are not original. I'm aware of the dropouts problem, and the guy who built it from parts and got the frame repainted told me he got them as modified as it was possible. I don't leave this bike in the street :D. It's probably a spanish manufacturers frame. I'll try to contact this guy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.99% sure that it's a generic plain "eBay" frame.  The kind you find for $200 or less online.  It's definitely not a reputable brand.

I couldn't find the one you have in your post.  Here is an example of a "track" frame on eBay.  It's inexpensive, unbranded, etc...:

[eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NIB-MTA-Single-Speed-Track-Fixie-Fixed-Frame-Fork-/200622664280)

I'd imagine that yours is similar, just the MTB version.